# Geeting axios error (500 Internal Server Error) unable to fetch ID

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, mern

This is ShowBook react code

## ShowBook.jsx

```
`import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import BackButton from '../components/BackButton';
import Spinner from '../components/Spinner';

const ShowBook = () => {
  const [book, setBook] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const {id} = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5555/books/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setBook(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [id]);
  

  return (
    <div className='p-4'>
      <BackButton /> 
      <h1 className='text-3xl my-4'>Show Book</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <div className='flex flex-col border-2 border-sky-400 rounded-xl w-fit p-4'>
          <div className='my-4'>
            <span className='text-xl mr-4 text-gray-500'>Id</span>
            <span>{book._id}</span>
          </div>
          <div className='my-4'>
            <span className='text-xl mr-4 text-gray-500'>Title</span>
            <span>{book.title}</span>
          </div>
          <div className='my-4'>
            <span className='text-xl mr-4 text-gray-500'>Author</span>
            <span>{book.author}</span>
          </div>
          <div className='my-4'>
            <span className='text-xl mr-4 text-gray-500'>Publish Year</span>
            <span>{book.publishYear}</span>
          </div>
          <div className='my-4'>
            <span className='text-xl mr-4 text-gray-500'>Create Time</span>
            <span>{new Date(book.createdAt).toString()}</span>
          </div>
          <div className='my-4'>
            <span className='text-xl mr-4 text-gray-500'>Last Update Time</span>
            <span>{new Date(book.updatedAt).toString()}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ShowBook;`
```

This is App.jsx react file

## App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import CreateBook from './pages/CreateBooks';
import ShowBook from './pages/ShowBook';
import EditBook from './pages/EditBooks';
import DeleteBook from './pages/DeleteBooks';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='/books/create' element={<CreateBook />} />
      <Route path='/books/details/:id' element={<ShowBook />} />
      <Route path='/books/edit/:id' element={<EditBook />} />
      <Route path='/books/delete/:id' element={<DeleteBook />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Why it is unable to fetch id? I am using postman to pass http requests. Please answer it as soon as possible. As I am trying to solve this but unable to understand how to do.. If possible please describe the reason for axios error.

Answer (score 0):

What version of React router are you using? If 6+ then can you try nesting the routes as shown below

```
<Route index element={<Home />} />
<Route path="books">
    <Route path="create" element={<CreateBook />} />
    <Route path=":id">
        <Route index element={<ShowBook />} />
        <Route path="edit" element={<EditBook />} />
        <Route path="delete" element={<DeleteBook />} />
    </Route>
</Route>
```

The above is working for me locally

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am using 6+ version but it is not working for me throwing this error- Received id: undefined
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Cat"

Comment: Try putting an if condition {if (id)} before fetching.